# Grunt serve "configureProxies:server" not found and "connect_proxy.js" error

Tags: node.js, grunt-connect-proxy

I'm trying to run a http server using grunt. However, when I type `grunt serve` in the appropriate directory, I'm presented with the following errors:

```
Loading "connect_proxy.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Running "serve" task
Warning: Task "configureProxies:server" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

My nodejs, node package manager, and ruby installations are at the following versions:

```
npm -v
1.3.10

nodejs -v
v0.10.25

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

How do I get the missing dependency? I've tried this both on Windows 8 and on a fresh install of elementaryOS Freya. The exact same problem arises on both. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was resolved by going into `package.json` and updating `"grunt-connect-proxy"` to `^0.2` to obtain the missing dependency.